# Prevent VNC from binding to IPv6 address

Tags: centos, vnc, ipv6

I have disabled IPv6 and I have found options to prevent MySQL, Postfix, CUPS and Telnet from binding to the IPv6 interface.

However, I can't find a way to disable it for VNC.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5901                 :::*                    LISTEN      6952/Xvnc
tcp6       0      0 :::6001                 :::*                    LISTEN      6952/Xvnc
```

Do you know how I can disable this?

Comment: How did you disable ipv6? Can you add the output of `ip -6 a l` to your question?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve by preventing this binding? Is it specifically harmful to your system?

Comment: Disable IPv6 in /etc/sysctl.conf ```net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1``` and ```net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1```. The were issues with Postfix connecting to IPv6 addresses so I disabled it.